# Filtering against query parameters, Many to many

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to filtering against query parameters in the URL by id.

For example: http://.../game/?category=1&level=1. Here are some pieces of my code:

---

*models.py*

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.ManyToManyField(Level)
```

*views.py*

```
class GamesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GamesListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Games.objects.all()
        category = self.request.query_params.get('category')
        level = self.request.query_params.get('level')

        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category_id=category)
```

How to filter the levels that are related by the relationship many to many with game?

Comment: `.filter(category_id=category, level__id=level)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Cannot resolve keyword 'level_id' into field.

Comment: @ShVavelinT: no, it is with *double* underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with `level=id_of_level`, or you can use `level__id=id_of_level` as well. SO you can implement this with:

```
class GamesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GamesListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Games.objects.all()
        category = self.request.query_params.get('category')
        level = self.request.query_params.get('level')

        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category_id=category)
        if level:
            queryset = queryset.filter(level=level)
        return queryset
```

Comment: with /game/?level=1. I have: 

{
       ...
        "level": [1]
    }

but i want to get:


{
       ...
        "level": 1
}

Comment: @ShVavilenT: this is only how it is represented in the `QueryDict`, if you use subscripting, or `.get(..)` it resolves to the last value (so `1`), for `.getlist(..)` it will resolve to `[1]`. This makes sense, since you can query with `?level=1&level=2`, so a `QueryDict` is a dictionary where the same key maps to possibly multiple values.

Comment: Can I do something to get one value?

Comment: @ShVavilenT: you already do that, by `self.request.query_params..get('level')`, you *get* one value, the last one if multiple have been passed.

Comment: @ShVavilenT: note that this is *not* a dictionary, it is `QueryDict`, so the behavior of `__getitem__`, etc. is altered.

Comment: I understand it.
Is it possible to make the value of the QueryDict not a list but a value?

Comment: @ShVavilenT: no, since a `QueryDict` is something that parses the querystring, and the querystring can contains the same key multiple times.